# Manage Querying from huge table which takes a lot time to alter/update

Tags: mysql

i have a very huge table `"table1"` from which i am continuously querying all day(24x7)

What happens is at the end of the day say at 12.AM, i run a query which would `alter "table1" at row level`. this activity takes around 3-4 hours till my updated `"table1"` is finished creating.

But till that time i wanted to still query from `"table1"`.

SO i decided to create two tables.   `"table1_active" and "table1_passive"`

normally during the day i will query from `"table1_passive"` and after i am updating "table1_active" i should switch my querying from `"table1_passive"`
to `"table1_active"`

and this switching should be done everyday, so that my all day querying should not hamper.

I dont know is there a better way to actually set a trigger or can anyone suggest me a method to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the use of a secondary table like `table1_passive` it's risky. You don't know exactly (as I understand) when the update process finish so you will don't know either when you should switch querying between `table1_passive` and `table1_active`.

There are several ways to improve the update process over your table but you have to keep in mind, those are **temporary** solutions if `table1` grows constantly:

- Use [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) as storage engine. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-queries-myisam.html) is a very good article about improve the updates over a MyISAM table.
- If you are updating `table1` based on a where clause, you might use [indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) to help database engine find which records has to update.
- Consider use [partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html) to work with your table faster.
- If you sill have those two tables, you can:

  1. Create an Unique_Index on `table1_active` and set [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
  2. Update `table1_passive`.
  3. Use [bulk insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html) in `table1_active` to speed up the process, the database will make sure that there are not duplicate rows based on your criteria.

BUT, if you are querying all day, and the table grows constantly I suggest to use NoSql because the problem will be there, even if you optimize the update process now.

If we could know the table structure and the update query you are using maybe we can help you better ;)

Regards and good luck!